# No commands whatsoever work with my discord.py bot. What is happening?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a discord bot with like two simple functions (client.event with client = discord.Client()) and recently I've been trying to work on commands for a music bot, but apparenly the bot doesn't even respond to the simplest commands there are. For example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command()
async def hello():
    print("Hello") #So when I type !hello in a channel I want "Hello" written in the console as prove that the bot is responding


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online.") #Just simple if the bot is online
```

The function client.event works of course but the bot.command() function wont react in any way. Can anyone help me here? I am really about to break everything I own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    print("Hello")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online.")


bot.run("Token")
```

Firstly, why are you defining client and bot simultaneously? Secondly you don't have `bot.run()` in your code. Thirdly you have to always give `ctx` in `@bot.command`.

Answer (score 0):

You either use `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot`, you cannot use both of them. If you take a look at your code, you're decorating the command with `bot.command()`, but at the end of the file you're running `client`. If you want commands I suggest you use `commands.Bot`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    print("Hello")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online.")

bot.run("XXX")
```